# How to get input of the 4th child of an element using class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<tr class='abc'>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
       <input></input>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I want to when i click input of the 4th child of tr , alert something,
what can i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**`nth:child`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector.

> The selector matches a number of `child elements` whose `numeric position` in the series of children matches the pattern *an+b*.

**`.abc td:nth-child(4) input`** => *Selects a `input` element from `4th td child` of parent `.abc` element.*

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.abc td:nth-child(4) input');
[].forEach.call(elems, function(elem) { //To iterate selected elements!
  elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('Clicked');
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class='abc'>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
    <td>
      <input>And some text(Not clickable)
    </td>
    <td>Five</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='abc'>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
    <td>Three</td>
    <td>
      <input>And some text(Not clickable)
    </td>
    <td>Five</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*Note:* As mentioned in comments, consider [*Browser compatibility*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Also note that Internet Explorer 8 (and earlier versions) would prevent this from working.

Comment: sorry. i ask not full.  we can use jquery. and the input tag not show from beginning. it only show after a event javascript. what can i do?

Comment: @sfblap, What is there in the page since beginning ? `table` ?

Comment: thank you. Problem is solved. $(document).on('click',".abc td:nth-child(4) input",function(){
 alert('something');
    });

Comment: @sfblap, Great..! [__`Event delegation`__](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) had to be used..

Answer (score 1):

I prefer use JQuery.

```
$("tr.abc").on("click", "td:eq(3) input", function(){
    console.log("click the fourth td")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery, you can try using the `nth-child()` selector.

Syntax:

```
$('.className element:nth-child(x)').whatever()...
```

Your case:

```
$('tr.abc td:nth-child(4)').whatever()...
```

Comment: The question isn't tagged with jQuery, but in any case your selector `'.abc:nth-child(4)'` will look for an element that has the class `abc` and that is also a 4th child. Which isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks for pointing out the error. I've suggested jQuery since OP says its available for him to use. Perhaps it could be added to the question tags

Answer (score 1):

`$( "tr li:nth-child(4)" )` would be the answer for more help please go tot the documentation of jquery. 
https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/
hope this answer your question.

Comment: The question isn't tagged with "jquery". Are you suggesting the OP should include an entire library to implement this one function?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your class has only one, so i call with 0 index.And you want 4th child so call with index 3 js array standard ,then your `input` has only one as index 0.

```
var g = document.getElementsByClassName("abc")[0];          
g.children[3].children[0].onclick = function(){
        alert('clicked');
}
```

If your element are more than one ,you can iterate with for loop...